# Munin on Centos 6 - missing perl MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8

Tags: centos, yum, perl, centos6, munin

I'm trying to install Munin on a new VPS through `yum install munin` but I keep getting an error about a missing perl module: `Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)`. This is the perl version currently installed: `v5.10.1`.

I've searched all around and still haven't found a solution for this.

Here's the relevant part of the output of the installation attempt:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-Mail-Sender-0.8.13-2.el5.1.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-Log-Log4perl-1.13-2.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-Mail-Sendmail-0.79-9.el5.1.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-Log-Dispatch-FileRotate-1.16-1.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-Crypt-DES-2.05-3.el5.i386 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: munin-1.4.7-5.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-IO-Multiplex-1.08-5.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: munin-common-1.4.7-5.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-Net-Server-0.96-2.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-Log-Dispatch-2.20-1.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: munin-1.4.7-5.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: bitstream-vera-fonts
Error: Package: perl-Net-SNMP-5.2.0-1.el5.1.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-HTML-Template-2.9-1.el5.2.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-IPC-Shareable-0.60-3.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Just to note that git (or the perl-Git package) on CentOS 6 also seems to have this broken dependency and the fix is the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using the EPEL 5 version of the repo instead of 6, go into your `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` file and change:

```
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-5&arch=$basearch
```

to

```
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
```

Then run `yum clean all` and then try and install munin again.

NOTE: you may have an issue with the GPG key being different, you need to grab the EPEL6 one or just use:

```
yum install munin --nogpgcheck
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've had this problem for a while going around in circles till I push it aside.  Now in 1 minute, your post has solved countless grey hairs and bald spots.

Comment: These directions worked on 2 of the 3 servers I was working on. The last one required me to do the following: `yum update --skip-broken`. Wanted to make a post in case anyone else needs it :)

Comment: Another option is for them to delete the file and perhaps install the correct repository :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you the yum configuration on the system is confused. It appears to be trying to install munin from the **Centos5** (hence all of those references to '.el5') repositories instead of from a **Centos6** repository and that will not work. Also once you have removed the Centos5 repositories from the configuration, be sure to run `yum clean all` before `yum install munin`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have CPanel look into /etc/yum.conf and take out perl* from exclude list

Answer (score 1):

just remove the repository form its place rm /etc/yum.repos.d/(added repository)
and yum clean all and yum install (whatever)